# Should I treat the frontend and backend of a webapp as ONE project, or as separate parts?

Tags: ember.js, express

Although requested by SO, the question title could be more specific, sorry for that ...

I try to learn Ember and Express.js, and at the moment I try to find my way through all the tools (yeoman, lineman) and development workflows. What I found is that the tutorials and tools either focus on the frontend *or* the backend, not both. For example, I can generate a project using Ember, or a project using express, but not a project using both.

I could imagine a project using both, and when I compile the project, I get separate folders for the server-side stuff and the client-side stuff.

Did I just browse the wrong sources, are there practical disadvantages or anything else?

**edit**

I found out that lineman, when used to create an Ember project, has this `config/server.js` file which allows to install some backends to test the ember app. This comes pretty close to what I was asking for. But still, it's only ment to *Define custom server-side endpoints to aid in development* (according to the lineman website).

Comment: There are projects that experiment on that https://github.com/mgenev/nodember Ember can work with any kind of backend that provides an api. So its doesn't make sense to create a tool that ties ember with a specific backend. Its just what I think. Lets see what the others have to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question depends on a couple things.

Feel free to do whatever you want in Ember, build the app you want. Indeed Ember can work with any back-end you choose.

Beware however, the same *cannot* be said about Ember-Data!  when it comes time to talk to your back end... Ember-Data expects the API from the server to conform pretty tightly to its own conventions. (at least not without a lot of re-configuring).

You can use an alternative like [Ember-Model](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model) or [RESTless](https://github.com/endlessinc/ember-restless) which can be more friendly to work with if your API uses a different convention.

So the choice is yours.  If you are creating everything from scratch, or if your back end developers can work with you on providing the specific conventions you need, it might be best to plan the front end and back end together so they come together nicely.

If your app plans to use some other 3rd party/public APIs take a look at their conventions and see if they might work with Ember-Data well, or if you will need to use one of the alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the several possibilities to tie ember to a specific backend, did not know about that.